# how to "reset" the whole /etc/apache2/ to factory defaults in SLES 11?

Tags: linux, rpm, sles, defaults

i got a SLES 11 sp3 Server where the whole /etc/apache2 seems to be messed up. If like to reset the whole thing to what i call "SuSE's factory defaults" so i can start over.

Any quick tip ?

Comment: As a quick and dirty hack, how about just extract those files from the apache rpm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my Problem:

zypper remove apache2-utils apache2-prefork apache2-example-pages apache2-doc apache2
zypper install apache2-utils apache2-prefork apache2-example-pages apache2-doc apache2

unlike other packet managers or software-installation user interfaces, it seems it "overwrites" configuration files that are already there (not really overwrites, but moves it away and replaces them).

So now the /etc/apache2 looks much like on its first day.